# Failing to setup my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Ruby on Rails running on Raspberry Pi 3/Raspbian (probably not a good idea), although I rarely encounter any issues. However, when I switched from SQLite to PostgreSQL for my database I get this strange error message that I cannot wrap my head around. I created a new Rails application using `rails new myapp --database=postgresql` which generated my application. I then went on to issue `rails db:setup` which is where I ran into the issue. I captured the error message into a text file using `rails db:setup &> error_message.txt`, which created a lengthy file. The first two lines are probably the most interesting:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:18: [BUG] Bus Error at 0x00aaa33b
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [armv7l-linux-eabihf]
```

My question is essentially: *is Ruby on Rails incompatible with ARM architectures?*

**Update 1:** I was able to get around this error by commenting out `require 'bootsnap/setup'` under `config/boot.rb`, but then I encounter this error instead:

```
** Invoke db:setup (first_time)
** Invoke db:schema:load_if_ruby (first_time)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:54: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000023
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [armv7l-linux-eabihf]
```

**Update 2:** I decided to setup my development environment on Debian 9 (executing on an x86 architecture), instead of my Raspbian (ARM architecture). I can now confirm that Ruby on Rails executes the aforementioned commands without generating any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Helo Mihkel,

I have RPi 2 and I didn't use as development machine because these type of boards work for IoT. I don't know what is your OS, but I highly recommended to change your development environment to Docker or Vagrant.

Anyway, let's look to this error

When I Google it, I found these solutions

- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/46217
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=69914#p511088

So, it seems SD problem or update. (If you solved, let me know)

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like Ruby on Rails isn't well-suited for ARM architectures due to a limited instruction set. I have instead decided to create a virtual machine on a proper x86 architecture for my future Rails development. Source: https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/67

Comment: Well, we can say that, @mihkel-pajunen, but did you try fresh SD card?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for that last error - You have to disable Spring

To do this go to your home/username folder, and type `ls -a`

There you see a file called `.bashrc`

Open this file:

```
$nano .bashrc
```

at the bottom you can add the following line:

```
export DISABLE_SPRING=true
```

save and exit file,

Then type in command line to activate it:

```
$source ~/.bashrc
```